# Shell Script to print row value of a particular index

Tags: linux, shell

I have a output like following:

```
S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC
31.59   0.00  20.69  44.69  59.67   8296   14.909 129667  621.433  636.342 CMS Final Remark     No GC
```

Now I need to pick particular key and value and print like:

```
S0,P,FGCT
31.59,59.67,621.433
```

how to pick particular index value in each row?
Please suggest

Comment: 1) will you always know the number of fields?"how many fields"

Comment: Use `awk`. When processing the first row, use a `for` loop to get the field numbers of the desired fields. Then when processing the second row print those fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way can be

```
awk '{ print $1 " " $5 " " $9 }' MyFileName
```

or if in some variable

```
echo $MyContent | awk '{ print $1 " " $5 " " $9 }'
```

EDIT2: 
This also works (tested on Linux)

```
echo "S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC
31.59   0.00  20.69  44.69  59.67   8296   14.909 129667  621.433  636.342 CMS Final Remark     No GC" \
| awk '{ print $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $4 "," $5 "," $11 "," $12 }'
```

Comment: Thanks this works for me. But I am not able to select last two values in my example i.e LGCC and GCC. I am doing something like:
awk 'NR==1{print $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $4 "," $5 "," $11 "," $12}' temp.txt
awk 'NR==2{print $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $4 "," $5 "," $11 "," $12}' temp.txt

But I am getting output as:

S0,S1,E,O,P,LGCC,GCC
0.00,28.50,11.71,37.05,59.67,CMS,Final

How can I get full value of this two indexes?

Comment: hey @NDeveloper look at my answer down below . i am able to extract any of the pos-params values :  awk -F " " 'NR==0{print;next} {printf "%s %s %s %s %s \n",$1,$5,$9 , $11 , $12}' myfile.txt

Comment: adapted example with $11 and $12

Answer (score 0):

The below follows an implementation in pure native shell (bash 4.x or newer) step-by-step:

```
## Read keys and values each into a separate array
## Note: If input is tab-delimited, have IFS=$'\t' set for these reads
{ read -r -a keys; read -r -a values; }

## Combine those two arrays into a single associative array mapping keys to values
declare -A content=( )
for idx in "${!keys[@]}"; do
  k=${keys[$idx]}
  v=${values[$idx]}
  content[$k]=$v
done

## ...take as input our set of desired keys...
desired_keys=( S0 P FGCH )

## ...and collect the associated values for each
output=( )
for k in "${desired_keys[@]}"; do
  output+=( "${content[$k]}" )
done

## With that done, we can emit our desired output:
IFS=,
printf '%s\n' "${desired_keys[*]}" "${output[*]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

awk is your friend.

```
[dev]$ cat myfile.txt 
S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC
31.59   0.00  20.69  44.69  59.67   8296   14.909 129667  621.433  636.342 CMS Final Remark     No GC


[dev]$ awk -F " " 'NR==0{print;next} {printf "%s %s %s \n",$1,$5,$9}' myfile.txt 
S0 P FGCT 
31.59 59.67 621.433
```

move `$1,$5,$9` around as wish . Make sure to add an additional `%s` for every newly selected value like `$7` ..

example : `printf "%s %s %s %s \n",$1,$5,$9,$7`

You can also change the delimiter from space to a dash by doing :

```
printf "%s-%s-%s \n",$1,$5,$9
```

or

```
printf "%s,%s,%s \n",$1,$5,$9
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a little hack with `echo` and `cut`:

```bash
data1="S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC"
data2="31.59   0.00  20.69  44.69  59.67   8296   14.909 129667  621.433  636.342 CMS Final Remark     No GC"

echo $data1 | cut -f 1,5,9 -d " " --output-delimiter=','
echo $data2 | cut -f 1,5,9 -d " " --output-delimiter=','
```

By storing the values in an intermediate variable and printing them with `echo` you will get only single spaces between the values.

This is basically the same as calling echo without quotes:

```
echo S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC | cut -f 1,5,9 -d " " --output-delimiter=','
echo 31.59   0.00  20.69  44.69  59.67   8296   14.909 129667  621.433  636.342 CMS Final Remark     No GC | cut -f 1,5,9 -d " " --output-delimiter=','
```

This will only work if there are no spaces in your values (obviously).